# R does not let me install packages

Tags: r, package

I am unable to install packages. I tried installing packages through the "Packages" Tab or writing install.packages("") in the console. However, both ways do not allow me to install the package.

Thank you in advance.

For instance, when I try to install devtools, I write install.packages("devtools") in the console and this is the following result:
`your text`

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘utf8’, ‘askpass’, ‘credentials’, ‘openssl’, ‘sys’, ‘zip’, ‘vctrs’, ‘fastmap’, ‘httpuv’, ‘mime’, ‘fontawesome’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘base64enc’, ‘sass’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘fansi’, ‘systemfonts’, ‘textshaping’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘pillar’, ‘highr’(, ‘diffobj’, ‘rematch2’, ‘curl’, ‘gert’, ‘gh’, ‘glue’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘purrr’, ‘rappdirs’, ‘yaml’, ‘cachem’, ‘shiny’, ‘htmltools’, ‘callr’, ‘processx’, ‘bslib’, ‘digest’, ‘downlit’, ‘httr’, ‘ragg’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘tibble’, ‘xml2’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘stringr’, ‘xopen’, ‘commonmark’, ‘knitr’, ‘stringi’, ‘brio’, ‘ps’, ‘waldo’, ‘usethis’, ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘fs’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘memoise’, ‘miniUI’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgdown’, ‘pkgload’, ‘profvis’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rlang’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘testthat’, ‘urlchecker’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/utf8_1.2.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 241412 bytes (235 KB)
==================================================
#...(repeats for all the dependencies...I just couldn't paste them because I was over the character limit)...#

* installing *source* package ‘utf8’ ...
** package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include  -Iutf8lite/src -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c as_utf8.c -o as_utf8.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [as_utf8.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘utf8’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/utf8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘sys’ ...
** package ‘sys’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c exec.c -o exec.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [exec.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sys’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/sys’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sys’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘zip’ ...
** package ‘zip’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  miniz.c zip.c unixutils.c tools/cmdzip.c -o tools/cmdzip
make: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: No such file or directory
make: *** [tools/cmdzip] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘zip’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/zip’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘zip’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘fastmap’ ...
** package ‘fastmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Ilib/  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include  -DR_NO_REMAP -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastmap.cpp -o fastmap.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++: command not found
make: *** [fastmap.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fastmap’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/fastmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fastmap’ had non-zero exit status

#...(repeats for all the dependencies...I just couldn't paste them because I was over the character limit)...#



x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c SpookyV2.cpp -o SpookyV2.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++: command not found
make: *** [SpookyV2.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/digest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘commonmark’ ...
** package ‘commonmark’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
rm -f cmark/cmark.o cmark/node.o cmark/iterator.o cmark/blocks.o cmark/inlines.o cmark/scanners.o cmark/utf8.o cmark/buffer.o cmark/references.o cmark/render.o cmark/man.o cmark/xml.o cmark/html.o cmark/commonmark.o cmark/latex.o cmark/houdini_href_e.o cmark/houdini_html_e.o cmark/houdini_html_u.o cmark/cmark_ctype.o cmark/arena.o cmark/linked_list.o cmark/plugin.o cmark/registry.o cmark/syntax_extension.o cmark/plaintext.o cmark/footnotes.o cmark/map.o extensions/autolink.o extensions/core-extensions.o extensions/ext_scanners.o extensions/strikethrough.o extensions/table.o extensions/tagfilter.o extensions/tasklist.o extensions.o init.o wrapper.o commonmark.dylib cmark/libstatcmark.a
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Icmark -I. -DCMARK_GFM_STATIC_DEFINE -DCMARK_GFM_EXTENSIONS_STATIC_DEFINE -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c extensions.c -o extensions.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [extensions.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘commonmark’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/commonmark’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘commonmark’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R
checking for R... /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/bin/R
checking for endianness... little
checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no
checking for cat... /bin/cat
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu69/data
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/yj/p3dzzr3j68l4n8jfmx4hx5mh0000gn/T/Rtmp6ihKhm/R.INSTALL1e244bd2be3b/stringi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/stringi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘brio’ ...
** package ‘brio’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c brio.c -o brio.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [brio.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘brio’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/brio’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brio’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘ps’ ...
** package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs  -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib -L/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib -Wall px.c -o px
make: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: No such file or directory
make: *** [px] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ps’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/ps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -I../inst/include -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c ansi.c -o ansi.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [ansi.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘fs’ ...
** package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv-1.44.2/include -I. -pthread  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c dir.cc -o dir.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++: command not found
make: *** [dir.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fs’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/fs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./rlang/  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1665472436697/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.2.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/programs/i386-mac/r/4.2.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c capture.c -o capture.o
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [capture.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sys’ is not available for package ‘askpass’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/askpass’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘askpass’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rlang’ is not available for package ‘later’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/later’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘later’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘systemfonts’ is not available for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/textshaping’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘xfun’ is not available for package ‘tinytex’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/tinytex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘xfun’ is not available for package ‘highr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/highr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘fastmap’ are not available for package ‘cachem’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/cachem’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cachem’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ps’ is not available for package ‘processx’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/processx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘cli’ is not available for package ‘desc’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/desc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘desc’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rlang’ is not available for package ‘ellipsis’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/ellipsis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ellipsis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘rversions’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/rversions’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘cli’ is not available for package ‘sessioninfo’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/sessioninfo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sessioninfo’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘curl’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘urlchecker’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/urlchecker’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘urlchecker’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘askpass’ is not available for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘later’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘promises’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/promises’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘promises’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘base64enc’, ‘rlang’, ‘fastmap’, ‘ellipsis’ are not available for package ‘htmltools’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/htmltools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘htmltools’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available for package ‘callr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/callr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘systemfonts’, ‘textshaping’ are not available for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/ragg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available for package ‘xopen’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/xopen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xopen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘highr’, ‘yaml’, ‘xfun’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/knitr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘cachem’ are not available for package ‘memoise’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/memoise’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘memoise’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘fs’, ‘glue’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘pkgload’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/pkgload’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘openssl’, ‘sys’, ‘curl’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘askpass’ are not available for package ‘credentials’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/credentials’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘credentials’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘promises’, ‘later’ are not available for package ‘httpuv’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/httpuv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘htmltools’ are not available for package ‘fontawesome’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/fontawesome’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fontawesome’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘fs’, ‘rlang’, ‘htmltools’, ‘rappdirs’ are not available for package ‘sass’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/sass’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sass’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘htmltools’ is not available for package ‘jquerylib’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/jquerylib’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jquerylib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘fansi’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘utf8’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘purrr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/purrr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘purrr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘brio’, ‘desc’, ‘digest’, ‘fansi’, ‘memoise’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘downlit’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/downlit’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘downlit’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘stringi’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘processx’ are not available for package ‘pkgbuild’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/pkgbuild’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgbuild’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘askpass’, ‘credentials’, ‘openssl’, ‘sys’, ‘zip’ are not available for package ‘gert’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/gert’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gert’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’ are not available for package ‘gh’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/gh’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gh’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘htmltools’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘sass’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘rlang’, ‘cachem’, ‘memoise’, ‘base64enc’, ‘mime’ are not available for package ‘bslib’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/bslib’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘curl’, ‘desc’, ‘digest’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘xopen’ are not available for package ‘rcmdcheck’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/rcmdcheck’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘commonmark’, ‘desc’, ‘knitr’, ‘pkgload’, ‘purrr’, ‘rlang’, ‘stringi’, ‘stringr’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘roxygen2’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/roxygen2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘roxygen2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘rematch2’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/rematch2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rematch2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘mime’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘fontawesome’, ‘htmltools’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘rlang’, ‘fastmap’, ‘commonmark’, ‘glue’, ‘bslib’, ‘cachem’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘lifecycle’ are not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bslib’, ‘htmltools’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘knitr’, ‘stringr’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘rmarkdown’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/rmarkdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘curl’, ‘desc’, ‘fs’, ‘gert’, ‘gh’, ‘glue’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘purrr’, ‘rappdirs’, ‘rlang’, ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘htmltools’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘yaml’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’ are not available for package ‘htmlwidgets’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/htmlwidgets’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘htmlwidgets’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘diffobj’, ‘fansi’, ‘glue’, ‘rematch2’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘waldo’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/waldo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘waldo’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘shiny’, ‘htmltools’ are not available for package ‘miniUI’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/miniUI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘miniUI’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bslib’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘digest’, ‘downlit’, ‘fs’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘memoise’, ‘purrr’, ‘ragg’, ‘rlang’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘tibble’, ‘xml2’, ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘pkgdown’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/pkgdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘profvis’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/profvis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘profvis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘brio’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘digest’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘pkgload’, ‘processx’, ‘ps’, ‘rlang’, ‘waldo’ are not available for package ‘testthat’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/testthat’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘cli’, ‘desc’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘fs’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘memoise’, ‘miniUI’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgdown’, ‘pkgload’, ‘profvis’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rlang’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘testthat’, ‘urlchecker’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Users/precisionvaccinesprogram/R/4.2.1/library/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/yj/p3dzzr3j68l4n8jfmx4hx5mh0000gn/T/Rtmpj3YoCc/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
```

Comment: What happened when you followed the prompts under the heading `------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------`?

Comment: Have you researched the `command not found` error, indicating it can't find `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`? My _guess_ (I don't run on macos) is you'll need xcode to install or repair the compiler/dev-environment.

Comment: An interim work-around might be to install binary packages instead of relying on compiling them. This will only work for CRAN (and BioC) packages (not for github/gitlab/local package source directories), see https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/ for one way of doing this.

Comment: As @PaulStaffordAllen indicates, you need to install `libxml2` on your system. If you just need `devtools` for `install_github()`, you can also use `remotes::install_github()`.